# How to visualise an interaction effect using ggplot with method = glmmTMB::glmmTMB and point weights

Tags: r, ggplot2, interaction

I am running an analysis in R on the effect of canopy cover (`OverheadCover`) and the number of carcasses placed on the same location (`CarcassNumber`) on the proportion of carrion eaten by birds (`ProportionBirdsScavenging`). The interaction effect `OverheadCover * CarcassNumber` is significant and I would like visualise this using ggplot like explained here: https://sebastiansauer.github.io/vis_interaction_effects/. I won't be using `method = "lm"` like in the example, but `method = glmmTMB::glmmTMB`. I've added the extra arguments `formula =` and `method.args =` to make sure R computes the smooth correctly.

This is how it should look, but I prefer the graph to be made with ggplot because then all my graphs will be in the same style.

```
glmm_interaction <- glmmTMB(ProportionBirdsScavenging ~ OverheadCover * CarcassNumber + (1|Area), data = data_both, beta_family(link = "logit"), weights = pointWeight_scaled)
plot_model(glmm_interaction, type = "int", ci.lvl = 0.682) # conf. int. of 68.3% -> ± standard error
```

[image]

This is the code I'm trying to run, but I can't get it to work. It keeps giving me errors, like `object 'pointWeight_scaled' not found`. Anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
qplot(x = OverheadCover, y = ProportionBirdsScavenging, color = CarcassNumber, data = data_both) +
  geom_smooth(method = glmmTMB::glmmTMB,
              formula = ProportionBirdsScavenging ~ OverheadCover * CarcassNumber,
              method.args = list(data = data_both, beta_family(link = "logit"), weights = pointWeight_scaled))
```

I know that it might be easier to just individually run the models and plot them on the same graph. I've done that, and it works. However, my calculated standard errors are larger than the ones in the `plot_model()`, so I wanted to see how these standard errors look if R does all the work, hence my intention to plot it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is how it should look, but I prefer the graph to be made with ggplot

The plot returned by `plot_model()` *is* a ggplot-object, which you can modify as you like. You could also use the [ggeffects-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/), which returns the underlying data that can be used to create the plot. There are many examples in the vignettes, both on how to create own plots or how to modify plots returned by `plot()`, e.g. [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/ggeffects.html) or [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_plotmethod.html).

Here is a toy example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix

set.seed(123)

dat <- data.frame(
  outcome = rbinom(n = 500, size = 1, prob = 0.25),
  var_binom = as.factor(rbinom(n = 500, size = 1, prob = 0.3)),
  var_cont = rnorm(n = 500, mean = 10, sd = 3),
  group = sample(letters[1:4], size =500, replace = TRUE)
)

model <- glmer(
  outcome ~ var_binom * poly(var_cont, 2) + (1 | group), 
  data = dat, 
  family = binomial(link = "logit")
)

predictions <- ggpredict(model, c("var_cont [all]", "var_binom"))

# plot-function from ggeffects
plot(predictions)
```

[image]

```r
# self made ggplot
ggplot(
  predictions, 
  aes(x = x, y = predicted, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, colour = group, fill = group)
) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(alpha = .1, colour = NA) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Daniel, I really appreciate the elaborate answer. It works. However, the plot made with the predictions from ```ggpredict``` seem te be made for only the x-values of the original data and is therefore quite angulated. I can't get ```ggpredict``` to predict values for a range of data with the ```new_data =``` argument. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Usually, `ggpredict()` shows a message that you could use the `[all]` tag to really compute predictions for all values along x (see my example above: `ggpredict(model, c("var_cont [all]", "var_binom"))`). This is because mixed models with a large range of values for the focal term may take some time to compute or even result in a memory allocation error. If you are certain that you can use all values, add the `[all]` tag. The related documentation with further details is here: https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_effectsatvalues.html